# How can I control the grippers in YuMi using the new abb_robot_driver

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using the new [abb_robot_driver](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver) to control ABB YuMi IRB 14000 using MoveIt, now I can neither read the position of the grippers in order to remap it into the joint states, nor command the grippers.

I have noticed that there are some services to control the grippers such as:

- /yumi/rws/sm_addin/set_sg_command

  ```
   Node: /yumi/rws_service_provider
   Type: abb_rapid_sm_addin_msgs/SetSGCommand
   Args: task command target_position
  ```

and:

- /yumi/rws/sm_addin/run_sg_routine

but I didn't know how to use them, can you please tell me how can I deal with the grippers [Read/Write]? thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391816/how-can-i-control-the-grippers-in-yumi-using-the-new-abb_robot_driver/) by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2021-11-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To command the grippers according to [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver_interfaces/blob/master/abb_rapid_sm_addin_msgs/srv/SetSGCommand.srv), I called the service:

- `rosservice call /yumi/rws/sm_addin/set_sg_command 'T_ROB_R' 7 0.0`

to open the gripper, but to activate this command I had to call the other service which is:

- `rosservice call /yumi/rws/sm_addin/run_sg_routine`.

Here is the list of the  grippers command services:

```
uint8 SG_COMMAND_UNKNOWN      = 1
uint8 SG_COMMAND_NONE         = 2
uint8 SG_COMMAND_INITIALIZE   = 3
uint8 SG_COMMAND_CALIBRATE    = 4
uint8 SG_COMMAND_MOVE_TO      = 5
uint8 SG_COMMAND_GRIP_IN      = 6
uint8 SG_COMMAND_GRIP_OUT     = 7
uint8 SG_COMMAND_BLOW_ON_1    = 8
uint8 SG_COMMAND_BLOW_ON_2    = 9
uint8 SG_COMMAND_BLOW_OFF_1   = 10
uint8 SG_COMMAND_BLOW_OFF_2   = 11
uint8 SG_COMMAND_VACUUM_ON_1  = 12
uint8 SG_COMMAND_VACUUM_ON_2  = 13
uint8 SG_COMMAND_VACUUM_OFF_1 = 14
uint8 SG_COMMAND_VACUUM_OFF_2 = 15
```

Still, I don't know how to read the position of the grippers, if you know how to do it, please feel free to leave a comment or even another answer, please.

---

Originally posted by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) with karma: 114 on 2021-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mahdi65](https://answers.ros.org/users/120244/mahdi65/) on 2022-10-10**:
Hi, Did you find the answer on how to read the gripper's position?

**Comment by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on 2022-10-11**:
@Mahdi65 not yet, but if you did let me know, please.

**Comment by [Mahdi65](https://answers.ros.org/users/120244/mahdi65/) on 2022-10-12**:
@bhomaidan There is a g_GetPos() method exist. But, the question is how to publish that value like joints on a separate topic? I could confirm it by printing the value on the Flex pendant.

**Comment by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on 2022-10-13**:
@Mahdi65, `g_GetPos()` is a RAPID instruction, bridging that to ROS is not straight forward, especially in realtime without delays!

**Comment by [Mahdi65](https://answers.ros.org/users/120244/mahdi65/) on 2022-10-13**:
@bhomaidan That is true. It is not really clear how they bridge the joint_states through RWS.

**Comment by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on 2022-10-13**:
@Mahdiford [State Machine AddIn](https://robotapps.robotstudio.com/#/viewApp/c163de01-792e-4892-a290-37dbe050b6e1) is the link between the robot and the ROS system, there might be a way to `Get` things in a similar way to [Set](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver_interfaces/tree/master/abb_rapid_sm_addin_msgs/srv)ing them, for instance [GetRAPIDNum](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver_interfaces/blob/master/abb_robot_msgs/srv/GetRAPIDNum.srv), but that might not work perfectly in real time!.

**Comment by [Mahdi65](https://answers.ros.org/users/120244/mahdi65/) on 2022-10-13**:
@bhomaidan I tried to dig both sides (RAPID and RWS). I did remove the EGM license to simplify the process. Even when the modules are not running, the robot keeps publishing the joint_states. I use [this](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver/tree/master/abb_robot_bringup_examples) for the sake of simplicity. I don't understand how they do that. The only part that I understand now is that they are using this function (void RWSStatePublisher::pollingTimerCallback(const ros::TimerEvent& event)) in the rws_state_publisher.cpp to access mechanical unit status, which is not presented in three main RAPID files (I am using just RWS as mentioned before).